# Swap content of 2 li's based on user selection

Tags: jquery, swap

I'm trying to swap list item content. First I click on one li and then I click on another and swap their content. It works the first time I try to exchange them, but each time after, it swaps the li's original content, not its new content. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm7Uq/27/).

```
<ul class="icecream">
    <li class="favorite" data-position="1" data-name="neopolitan">Neopolitan</li>
    <li class="favorite" data-position="2" data-name="mintchip">Mint Chip</li>
    <li class="favorite" data-position="3" data-name="vanilla">Vanilla</li>
    <li class="option" data-position="NA" data-name="chocolate">Chocolate</li>
    <li class="option" data-position="NA" data-name="cookiesncream">Cookies'n'Cream</li>
    <li class="option" data-position="NA" data-name="rockyroad">Rocky Road</li>
</ul>

$(document).on("click",  "ul.icecream>li" , function(){
     if($("ul.icecream>li").hasClass("active")){
         if($(this).hasClass("subactive")){
             $(this).removeClass("subactive");
         }
         else{
             var p1_name = $("ul.icecream>li.active").data("name");
             var p_name = $(this).data("name");
             $(this).attr("data-name", p1_name).text(p1_name);
             $("ul.icecream>li.active").attr("data-name", p_name).text(p_name).removeClass("active");
         }
     }
     else{
         $(this).addClass("active");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `attr("data-name", p_name)` to `data("name", p_name)`. Do the same for `p1_name`. `attr` is corruption things somewhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vm7Uq/43/

Comment: Tried everything...never would have thought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**this might be easier**

```
$('li.option,li.favorite').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');//toggle active
    if ($('li.active').length>1) {//if more than 1
        var na = [];//make array
        $('li.active').each(function() { var th = $(this).text(); na.push(th); })//for each active, get text & push to array
        .each(function(i) {
            i = i ? 0 : 1;//swap i
            $(this).data('name', na[i].toLowerCase()).text(na[i]).removeClass('active');//swap info & remove active   
        });
    }
});
```

Everytime an `li.option` or `li.favorite` is clicked and marked active, if there is more than one, then it pushes the two values to an array and swaps them, converts it to lowercase and swaps the `data-name`, then removes the `active` class.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/88qPZ/